# Acumatica - Install Multiple Versions on one Machine

Tags: docker, windows-installer, acumatica

Can I use Acumatica in Docker?
I want to have multiple versions on one machine.

The Windows Installer will not allow me to install more than one version of the same program. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose you already have Acumatica 20.093.0108 installed and you wanna have an older version 19.193.0108 "Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard" for some reason (you need older DB, or site or whatever). In this case, you can silently extract any version to the needed folder, just take 19.193.0108 build, find **AcumaticaERPInstall.msi**

```
19.193.0108\AcumaticaERP\AcumaticaERPInstall.msi
```

run installation via Terminal or .bat file as follows

```
@msiexec /a AcumaticaERPInstall.msi /qb TARGETDIR=C:\AcumaticaBuilds\19.193.0108
```

and run Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard using

```
C:\19.193.0108\AcumaticaBuilds\Acumatica ERP\Data\AcumaticaConfig.exe
```